# Regression plot is wrong (python)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

So my program reads MPG vs weight relationship and draws a graph of what it is suppose to look like but as you can see the graph is not looking right.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read txt file
dataframe= pd.read_table('auto_data71.txt',delim_whitespace=True,names=['MPG','Cylinder','Displacement','Horsepower','Weight','acceleration','Model year','Origin','Car Name'])
dataframe.dropna(inplace=True)

#filter the un-necessary columns
X = dataframe.iloc[:,4:5].values
Y = dataframe.iloc[:,0:1].values


#scale data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_Y= StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
Y = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y)

#split data into train and test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

#create model
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly_X = poly_reg.fit_transform(x_train)
poly_reg.fit(poly_X,y_train)
regressor2= LinearRegression()
regressor2.fit(poly_X,y_train)


#graph
result = regressor2.predict(poly_X)
plt.scatter(x_train,y_train,color='red')
plt.plot(x_train, result,color='blue')
plt.show()
```

the output is this:
As you can see the regression line does not look right. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: as you can see the regression line does not look right. Any help will be much appreciated]

```
#auto_data.txt(part of data...)
```

****NOTE:i am only using weight and mpg column for this code
file(mpg,cylinder,distance,horsepower,weight,acceleration,year,origin,name)

```
27.0   4.   97.00      88.00      2130.      14.5   71.  3. "datsun pl510"
28.0   4.   140.0      90.00      2264.      15.5   71.  1. "chevrolet vega 2300"
25.0   4.   113.0      95.00      2228.      14.0   71.  3. "toyota corona"
25.0   4.   98.00      NA         2046.      19.0   71.  1. "ford pinto"
NA     4.   97.00      48.00      1978.      20.0   71.  2. "volkswagen super beetle 117"
19.0   6.   232.0      100.0      2634.      13.0   71.  1. "amc gremlin"
16.0   6.   225.0      105.0      3439.      15.5   71.  1. "plymouth satellite custom"
17.0   6.   250.0      100.0      3329.      15.5   71.  1. "chevrolet chevelle malibu"
19.0   6.   250.0      88.00      3302.      15.5   71.  1. "ford torino 500"
18.0   6.   232.0      100.0      3288.      15.5   71.  1. "amc matador"
14.0   8.   350.0      165.0      4209.      12.0   71.  1. "chevrolet impala"
14.0   8.   400.0      175.0      4464.      11.5   71.  1. "pontiac catalina brougham"
14.0   8.   351.0      153.0      4154.      13.5   71.  1. "ford galaxie 500"
14.0   8.   318.0      150.0      4096.      13.0   71.  1. "plymouth fury iii"
12.0   8.   383.0      180.0      4955.      11.5   71.  1. "dodge monaco (sw)"
13.0   8.   400.0      170.0      4746.      12.0   71.  1. "ford country squire (sw)"
13.0   8.   400.0      175.0      5140.      12.0   71.  1. "pontiac safari (sw)"
18.0   6.   258.0      110.0      2962.      13.5   71.  1. "amc hornet sportabout (sw)"
```

Comment: You need to sort the values before plotting. Can you add the data ?

Comment: i added the data,thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I am going to post an answer soon

Comment: i added dataframe.sort_values(by='Weight',inplace=True) after dataframe.dropna(inplace=True) and the graph still looks jumbled up

Comment: see my answer and let me know. Keep in mind that you are trying to plot the `x_train` and the `result` but `result` is the predicted polynomial features

Comment: You can also use `scatter` on both, instead of calling `plot` for the blue line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **sort** the values before plotting.

DATA: https://files.fm/u/2g5dxyb4

**Use this**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
data.dropna(inplace=True)

X = data['weight'].values
Y = data['mpg'].values

X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

#scale data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_Y= StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
Y = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y)

#split data into train and test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

#create model
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly_X = poly_reg.fit_transform(x_train)
poly_reg.fit(poly_X,y_train)
regressor2= LinearRegression()
regressor2.fit(poly_X,y_train)


#graph
result = regressor2.predict(np.sort(poly_X,axis=0))
plt.scatter(x_train,y_train,color='red')
plt.plot(np.sort(x_train, axis = 0), result,color='blue')
plt.show()
```